# Cookies are not getting set at the page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I  need to set some cookies when user visit for the very first time on page. So I clear the cookie of my browser and then try to load my project. After clearing cookie. Cookie is not being set at page load. I am working on MVC 5 with Razor

This is my javascript code

```
  <script src="~/Content/JavaScript/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Content/JavaScript/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            getCookie("user_id");
            if (getCookie("user_id") == "") {
                var user_id = guid();
                setCookie("user_id", user_id, 365);
            }

            var currency_id = getCookie("currency_id")
            if (currency_id == "" || currency_id == null) {
                setCookie("currency_id", "1", 365);
                setCookie("currency_code", "INR", 365);
                setCookie("currency_rate", "1", 365);
            }
            else {
                ChangeCurrencyValue(currency_id)
            }
            ShowCart();
            ShowWishList();

        });
        </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
        }
        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
            return "";
        }
      function guid() {
            function s4() {
                return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                  .toString(16)
                  .substring(1);
            }
            return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
              s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
        }
        </script>
```

I have already tried putting code in `<head>` block its not working

Comment: `</script>
 function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {` you have to put it in the script block not outside.

Comment: Its in the script block only I just copied here wrong way. I will edit it

Comment: you have to put functions in one script block or you might change the script blocks order. put functions script block upwards before you are calling functions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue i guess is the script execution order. You are trying to call a function which is in different script block and you are calling it before getting registered in the browser.

Try to put all the functions and other codes in one script block instead of different ones:

```
<script src="~/Content/JavaScript/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/JavaScript/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        getCookie("user_id");
        if (getCookie("user_id") == "") {
            var user_id = guid();
            setCookie("user_id", user_id, 365);
        }

        var currency_id = getCookie("currency_id")
        if (currency_id == "" || currency_id == null) {
            setCookie("currency_id", "1", 365);
            setCookie("currency_code", "INR", 365);
            setCookie("currency_rate", "1", 365);
        }
        else {
            ChangeCurrencyValue(currency_id)
        }
        ShowCart();
        ShowWishList();

    });
  // -------##########---remove the closing script tag---#######
 function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
        return "";
    }
  function guid() {
        function s4() {
            return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
              .toString(16)
              .substring(1);
        }
        return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
          s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
    }
    </script>
```